# How to run exe file in php

Tags: php, python, exe

I'm working on classification algorithm in python and it related with php code, to get the right result I should run my python exe then go to the php code.

I want to execute the python by itself with php code. I tried this:

```
<?php
// outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
// (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

But It's not working, should I know more about path? and how to put my exe in the write path?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "not working" entails?

Comment: @castis Nothing happened, no result until I open exe file by myself.

Comment: sorry the comment right above the echo line explains why "its not working" ... there is not much more we can do to explain ... try changing "whoami" to an actual windows command ("ipconfig" maybe) since it sounds like thats the OS you are on...if the exe is in the same directory the php is executing from you can probably just change whoami to "some.exe"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
exec("C:\\Users\\posh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\python.exe YOUR_PYTHONSCRIPT.py <arguments if any>", $output, $ret_code);
// directly writing python may not work in that case 
// give path to python.exe
exec("python YOUR_PYTHONSCRIPT.py <arguments if any>", $output, $ret_code);
// $ret_code : returns the code 0 or 1
// output is an array
?>
```

Comment: Please don't just post arbitrary code snippets (especially not `exec()` calls...). Explain what you're doing and why it solves OP's problem, so they can learn from the experience.